# superuser being able to create multiple posts while restricted one post for one user rule kept

Tags: python, django

I asked similar question before but when I think it got fixed I get error after error from out of nowhere. As a superuser I want to create multiple categories and restrict others to have only one. I have successfully restricted users to post only one, but I can only post one as well. When I try to do it, I get IntegrityError at /add_category/
UNIQUE constraint failed: main_category.author_id

Here;s my code

models.py

```
class Category(models.Model): 
    name = models.CharField(max_length=128, unique=True)
    description = models.CharField(max_length=200, unique=True)
    image = models.FileField(upload_to='images',blank=True, null=True)
    author = models.OneToOneField(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, unique=True)


    def __unicode__(self):
```

views.py

```
@login_required
def add_category(request):
    if not request.user.is_superuser and Category.objects.filter(author=request.user).exists():
        return render(request,'main/category_already_exists.html')
    if request.method == 'POST':
        category = Category(author=request.user)
        form = CategoryForm(request.POST, request.FILES, instance=category)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save(commit=True)
            return redirect('index')

    else:
        form = CategoryForm()

    return render(request, 'main/add_category.html', {'form':form})
```

thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should change the 'author' field to a **ForeignKeyField**

A one-to-one relationship. Conceptually, this is similar to a ForeignKey with unique=True, but the “reverse” side of the relation will directly return a single object.

models.py

```
class Category(models.Model): 
name = models.CharField(max_length=128, unique=True)
description = models.CharField(max_length=200, unique=True)
image = models.FileField(upload_to='images',blank=True, null=True)
author = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL)


def __unicode__(self):
```